# Question-title Inconsistency in Profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, title

Closed questions listed in the "Answers" portion of a user-profile don't show `[closed]` in their titles, but do in the "Questions" portion of a user-profile. Shouldn't the title contain this appendage everywhere it's displayed?

Update: This is also the case in "Recent Activity" page and the "Activity Tab."

Comment: The question title doesn't contain "[closed]".

Answer (score 6):

I think doing this would give the inappropriate impression that the *answer* has been closed.

Comment: Silly rabbit, close votes are for questions!

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're getting at, but I am not sure I agree. The answer isn't closed, but the question is.