# Show full question title including Closed for closed questions in the reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, closed-questions, title, reputation-history

Currently the reputation tab (and maybe others) on a user's profile page doesn't show [Closed] on questions that were closed.

I think it should, as it is shown in many other places.

Comment: What about reputation gained for answers? As was already [discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46668/question-title-inconsistency-in-profiles?rq=1) it will "give the inappropriate impression that the answer has been closed"

Comment: Personally I think it should be everywhere where there is a question title, but I can see why it might create confusion, particularly on a page with only answers.

Comment: Why would that be useful?

Comment: @Yannis I think the goal here is to make things more consistent.