# Under profile on all actions, closed status isn't indicated on questions

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, closed-questions

On your profile, when you go to your 'all actions', I'm trying to find certain questions which may be reopened - that is, no longer closed (cough hats cough).

[Example on my profile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=4)

Several of these are closed, but you can't tell until you click them.

Almost everywhere else, it'd indicated [Closed] or [Duplicate] or whatever.

It'd be useful to get this fixed/added?

Comment: Related: [Question-title Inconsistency in Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46668/289905)